# Mobile Responsive Menus - If a sub menu appears (Show a link)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Trying to build a mobile responsive menu. Some items have a class of "sub-menu" underneath an li (Site is built in Wordpress)

What I'd like to do is on a tablet / mobile device, Is show an arrow on the parent li and when the link is clicked toggled the sub-menu (Allowing me to show and hide child pages, But they can still be accessed).

My menu markup looks as follows :

```
<ul id="menu-site-menu" class="site-menu"><li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-150"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-171" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-171"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/why-us/">Why us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-175"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/why-us/our-experts/">Our Experts</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-172" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-172"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/why-us/about-us/">About us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-176" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-176"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/why-us/testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-173" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-173"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/why-us/case-studies/">Case Studies</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-174" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-174"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/why-us/faqs/">FAQ’s</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-155"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/finance/">Finance</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-160"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/finance/commercial-mortgage/">Commercial Mortgage</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-157" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-157"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/finance/bridging-finance/">Bridging Finance</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-161" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-161"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/finance/development-finance/">Development Finance</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-162" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-162"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/finance/residential-investment-finance/">Residential Investment Finance</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-156" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-156"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/finance/asset-finance/">Asset Finance</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-163" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-163"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/finance/secured-loans/">Secured Loans</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-158" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-158"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/finance/cashflow-finance/">Cashflow Finance</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-159"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/finance/commercial-investment-finance/">Commercial Investment Finance</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-151" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-151"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/alternative-funding/">Alternative Funding</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-152" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-152"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/alternative-funding/crowd-funding/">Crowd Funding</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-166" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-166"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/protection/">Protection</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-169"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/protection/wills-estate-planning/">Wills &amp; Estate Planning</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-167" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-167"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/protection/business-protection/">Business Protection</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-168" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-168"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/protection/personal-protection/">Personal Protection</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-165" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-165"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/news/">News</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-170" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-170"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/resources/">Resources</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-154" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-154"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/contact/">Contact</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-153"><a href="http://localhost/commercialexpert.co.uk/apply-for-funding/">Apply</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see some have a "sub-menu" that is where I'd like to toggle. Not sure how to do this, So any help much appreciated, As it will help me with future projects too.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
css file

```
@media all and (max-width: 991px) {
    .menu-item > ul.sub-menu { display: none; }
    .menu-item-has-children:after {
        content: '+';
    }
}
```

js file with jquery

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle();
})
```